# Kubectl like output format for my cobra project

Tags: go, kubectl, cobra

I am new to golang and trying to develop a commandline tool using cobra. I would like to provide flags like kubectl offers to it's users. As a first step i would like to implement kubectl standard format like this

```
kubectl get pods -n mpo
NAME                                                    READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
my-deployment-5588bf7844-n2nw7                        1/1     Running     0          3d
my-deployment-5588bf7844-qcpsl                        1/1     Running     0          3d
```

Could please direct me to a simple example project *(kubectl github project is too difficult for me to understand)* or code where i could understand how to implement this output format.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The efficient way to print a table in GO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36101534/the-efficient-way-to-print-a-table-in-go)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can format strings in Go with padding on either side. See [this post](https://gosamples.dev/string-padding/) for example.

Below, I format all strings with right padding. The first column gets 40 char padding as the pod name might be long. The other columns get only 10 chars padding.

```golang
fmt.Printf("%-40s %-10s %-10s\n", "NAME", "READY", "STATUS")
fmt.Printf("%-40s %-10s %-10s\n", "my-deployment-5588bf7844-n2nw7", " 1/1", "Running")
fmt.Printf("%-40s %-10s %-10s\n", "my-deployment-5588bf7844-n2nw7", " 1/1", "Running")
}
```

https://play.golang.com/p/8ZZH5XmqTpR

That said, using [tabwriter](https://pkg.go.dev/text/tabwriter), may be another, potentially even better option.

```golang
// io.Writer, minwidth, tabwidth, padding int, padchar byte, flags uint
w := tabwriter.NewWriter(os.Stdout, 10, 1, 5, ' ', 0)
fmt.Fprintln(w, "NAME\tREADY\tSTATUS")
fmt.Fprintln(w, "my-deployment-5588bf7844-n2nw7\t1/1\tRunning")
fmt.Fprintln(w, "my-deployment-5588bf7844-n2nw7\t1/1\tRunning")
w.Flush()
```

https://play.golang.com/p/QS01cuR34Jx